# PHP Facebook SDK API get multiple feeds in one request

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am watching 2 pages for used car parts. I want to call both page feeds in a single call sorted by last post. I am trying this code but it doesn't work...

```
/* PHP SDK v4.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $sess,
  'GET',
  //'/89641180016/feed' //single call works!
   '/89641180016/feed','/93811111500/feed' //multiple call fails
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->AsArray();
/* handle the result */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `/feed?ids=89641180016,93811111500` (see doc: [Making Multiple Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#multirequests))

Comment: when i use that i get a error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/zefex/public_html/index.php on line 152

`foreach ($graphObject['data'] as $key => $value){`

Comment: It seems to be working, when i  print_r this is the array i get: 

`Array
(
    [89647580016] => stdClass Object
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 89647580016_10153022674865017
                            [from] => stdClass Object
                                (
`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [FacebookRequest](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php) class, I think that you can only call one path per one FacebookRequest.

Maybe try wrapping your call in a `foreach`?